# undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPSStreamFactory::registerFactory()'

Tags: openframeworks

I have downloaded the latest version of open-frameworks 64 bit and run the below scripts,

```
sudo ./install_dependencies.sh
sudo ./install_codeblocks.sh
sudo ./install_codecs.sh
sudo ./compileOF.sh
```

All the scripts run successfully. I then ran the `testAllExamples.sh`, in which I face no problems.

I downloaded and copied "ofxCv" and "ofxFaceTracker" into addons folder.

My intentions is to compile the [Facesubstitution](https://github.com/arturoc/FaceSubstitution) code. 
I downloaded the source of the facesubstitution-master and tried compiling the "Facesubstituion" project in it. It shows the below error.

Can some one help me solve the below error.

```
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_core.a(system.o): In function `cv::tempfile(char const*)':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv8tempfileEPKc+0x2f): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofURLFileLoader.o): In function `ofURLFileLoader::ofURLFileLoader()':
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x2686): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPSStreamFactory::registerFactory()'
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x269d): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::KeyConsoleHandler::KeyConsoleHandler(bool)'
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x26e1): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::ConsoleCertificateHandler::ConsoleCertificateHandler(bool)'
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x2767): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Context::Context(Poco::Net::Context::Usage, std::string const&, Poco::Net::Context::VerificationMode, int, bool, std::string const&)'
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x27ec): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance()'
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x280c): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::SSLManager::initializeClient(Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::PrivateKeyPassphraseHandler> >, Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> >, Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::Context>)'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofURLFileLoader.o): In function `ofURLFileLoader::handleRequest(ofHttpRequest)':
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x370e): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession::HTTPSClientSession(std::string const&, unsigned short)'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofURLFileLoader.o): In function `ofURLFileLoaderShutdown()':
ofURLFileLoader.cpp:(.text+0x354c): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::uninitializeSSL()'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstVideoGrabber.o): In function `ofPixelFormatFromGstFormat(std::string)':
ofGstVideoGrabber.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `gst_video_format_from_string'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstVideoGrabber.o): In function `ofGstVideoGrabber::listDevices()':
ofGstVideoGrabber.cpp:(.text+0x21cd): undefined reference to `gst_video_format_from_string'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstVideoGrabber.o): In function `add_video_format(ofGstDevice&, ofGstVideoFormat&, _GstStructure&, int)':
ofGstVideoGrabber.cpp:(.text+0x2fb2): undefined reference to `gst_video_format_from_string'
ofGstVideoGrabber.cpp:(.text+0x3678): undefined reference to `gst_video_format_from_string'
ofGstVideoGrabber.cpp:(.text+0x3728): undefined reference to `gst_video_format_from_string'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstVideoGrabber.o):ofGstVideoGrabber.cpp:(.text+0x3880): more undefined references to `gst_video_format_from_string' follow
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstUtils.o): In function `on_new_buffer_from_source(_GstAppSink*, void*)':
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `gst_app_sink_pull_sample'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstUtils.o): In function `ofGstVideoUtils::update()':
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x2e7): undefined reference to `gst_app_sink_pull_sample'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `gst_sample_get_buffer'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `gst_buffer_map'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x38a): undefined reference to `gst_buffer_unmap'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstUtils.o): In function `ofGstVideoUtils::preroll_cb(_GstSample*)':
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4a42): undefined reference to `gst_sample_get_buffer'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4a5c): undefined reference to `gst_buffer_map'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4afb): undefined reference to `gst_buffer_unmap'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4c21): undefined reference to `gst_sample_get_caps'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4c2e): undefined reference to `gst_video_info_init'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4c3b): undefined reference to `gst_video_info_from_caps'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4c55): undefined reference to `gst_video_frame_map'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x4c6a): undefined reference to `gst_video_frame_unmap'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a(ofGstUtils.o): In function `ofGstVideoUtils::buffer_cb(_GstSample*)':
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x5132): undefined reference to `gst_sample_get_buffer'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x514c): undefined reference to `gst_buffer_map'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x51eb): undefined reference to `gst_buffer_unmap'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x5311): undefined reference to `gst_sample_get_caps'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x531e): undefined reference to `gst_video_info_init'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x532b): undefined reference to `gst_video_info_from_caps'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x5345): undefined reference to `gst_video_frame_map'
ofGstUtils.cpp:(.text+0x535a): undefined reference to `gst_video_frame_unmap'
obj/x86_64Release/src/testApp.o: In function `testApp::setup()':
testApp.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `Clone::setup(int, int)'
obj/x86_64Release/src/testApp.o: In function `testApp::update()':
testApp.cpp:(.text+0x645): undefined reference to `Clone::setStrength(int)'
testApp.cpp:(.text+0x6a6): undefined reference to `Clone::update(ofTexture&, ofTexture&, ofTexture&)'
obj/x86_64Release/src/testApp.o: In function `testApp::draw()':
testApp.cpp:(.text+0x777): undefined reference to `Clone::draw(float, float)'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_imgproc.a(templmatch.o): In function `cv::crossCorr(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::Point_<int>, double, int)':
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x39e): undefined reference to `cv::getOptimalDFTSize(int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x3dd): undefined reference to `cv::getOptimalDFTSize(int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0xcd7): undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x19bb): undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1a6f): undefined reference to `cv::mulSpectrums(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, bool)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x1ab6): undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvHoughLines':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvHoughLines+0x44): undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvHoughLinesP':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvHoughLinesP+0x4a): undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvHoughLinesSDiv':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvHoughLinesSDiv+0x48): undefined reference to `cvHoughLines2'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_legacy.a(compat.o): In function `cvCalcEMD':
compat.cpp:(.text.cvCalcEMD+0x9d): undefined reference to `cvCalcEMD2'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_calib3d.a(calibinit.o): In function `cv::findCirclesGrid(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> const&)':
calibinit.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv15findCirclesGridERKNS_11_InputArrayENS_5Size_IiEERKNS_12_OutputArrayEiRKNS_3PtrINS_15FeatureDetectorEEE+0x164): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_calib3d.a(circlesgrid.o): In function `cv::findCirclesGridDefault(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)':
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv22findCirclesGridDefaultERKNS_11_InputArrayENS_5Size_IiEERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x30): undefined reference to `cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params::Params()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv22findCirclesGridDefaultERKNS_11_InputArrayENS_5Size_IiEERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x48): undefined reference to `cv::SimpleBlobDetector::SimpleBlobDetector(cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params const&)'
/home/hub/Downloads/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_calib3d.a(circlesgrid.o): In function `CirclesGridClusterFinder::parsePatternPoints(std::vector<cv::Point_<float>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<float> > > const&, std::vector<cv::Point_<float>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<float> > > const&, std::vector<cv::Point_<float>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<float> > >&)':
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x28): undefined reference to `cv::flann::LinearIndexParams::LinearIndexParams()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x13c): undefined reference to `cv::flann::Index::Index(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::flann::IndexParams const&, cvflann::flann_distance_t)'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x3ef): undefined reference to `cv::flann::SearchParams::SearchParams(int, float, bool)'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x4d4): undefined reference to `cv::flann::Index::knnSearch(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, cv::flann::SearchParams const&)'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x4e1): undefined reference to `cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x60b): undefined reference to `cv::flann::Index::~Index()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x618): undefined reference to `cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x692): undefined reference to `cv::flann::Index::~Index()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x69f): undefined reference to `cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x6b7): undefined reference to `cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()'
circlesgrid.cpp:(.text._ZN24CirclesGridClusterFinder18parsePatternPointsERKSt6vectorIN2cv6Point_IfEESaIS3_EES7_RS5_+0x6fc): undefined reference to `cv::flann::Index::~Index()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/FaceSubstitution] Error 1
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I tried to use the settings from config.linux.common.mk file including it to the config.make file of  FaceSubstitution, but no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work. Briefly, the solution is: **use the projectGenerator from openFrameworks!**

I successfully started the FaceSubstitution app on Ubuntu 14.04 [with OpenCV 2.4.9] by following these steps:

1. Install openFrameworks.

   Download [of_v0.8.3_linux64_release.tar.gz](http://www.openframeworks.cc/versions/v0.8.3/of_v0.8.3_linux64_release.tar.gz) and extract anywhere.

   Run the following installation scripts from the folder *of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/scripts/linux/ubuntu*

   > install_dependencies.sh, install_codecs.sh

   Run the following compilation scripts from the folder *of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/scripts/linux/*

   > compileOF.sh, compilePG.sh
2. Install ofxCV.

   Simply clone from git to *of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons*.

   > cd of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons && git clone https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv.git
3. Install ofxFaceTracker.

   Again clone from git to *of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons*.

   > git clone https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxFaceTracker.git
4. Download FaceSubstitution anywhere.

   Run the projectGenerator from *of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/projectGenerator*.

   Create a new project for CloningWrapper and FaceSubstitution. Select all the addons (we probably just need the ones related to the error messages, but it doesn't hurt to simply take all /only the compilation time will be longer/).

   Copy the source files from the downloaded FaceSubstitution folder to these newly created folders respectively.

   Compile CloningWrapper (*make*) and change the config.make file of FaceSubstitution as follows:

   > PROJECT_LDFLAGS= [path to CloningWrapper]/obj/linux64/Release/Clone.o
   >
   > PROJECT_CFLAGS = -I [path to CloningWrapper]/src

   Compile FaceSubstitution (*make*). It should be successful now.
5. Copy the *of_v0.8.3_linux64_release/addons/ofxFaceTracker/libs/FaceTracker/model* folder to *[path to FaceSubstitution]/bin/data* and a *face.jpg* file to *[path to FaceSubstitution]/bin/data/faces*.
6. If your webcam is connected and functional you may start the application. (*make run*)

I hope it works for you as well.